# PHP require_once() .js file

Tags: javascript, php, require-once

Okay, so I'm using require_once to load the contents of a .js file. However, there seems to be a `1` added to the end of the file after the require is done.

PHP:

```
echo require_once("test.js");
```

JS:

```
var newFunc = function() {
    console.log('yay!');
};
```

rendered html when the PHP file is loaded:

```
var newFunc = function() {
    console.log('yay!');
};1
```

Comment: The way you are doing it seems completely contrary to best practices. You should add your scripts by using script tags.

Comment: Objection noted, but this is for a document loaded via Ajax. I have a function that appends JS code to a script tag after the request has loaded.

Comment: require_once is closely same as [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and is mainly targeted for including php-scripts. Do not use it to include js.

Comment: Seems to me you are leaving your site wide open to a JS injection vulnerability. Maybe you can see some other way you could achieve your goals?

Comment: @Ermir this is not applied to anything submitted by a user.

Comment: @Ermir any suggestions on loading javascript per ajax page request?

Comment: Place your different scripts in different files, and then get only the URL of the script that you need. This way, you can then just create a script element in HTML and set the src attribute as the URL you just got. What this achieves is guaranteeing that only code written in predefined script files can be loaded, so it's safer. To really secure such as system, make sure to activate [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @Ermir I decided to experiment with your idea. In order for it to remain dynamic enough, I decided that the ajax page would tell javascript to load its custom JS or CSS files with a header. This way a user couldn't inject a header (as they are sent before any user content is rendered), thus keeping the script secure and dynamically loadable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[require_once()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.require-once.php) returns 1 if the include was successful. So you're echoing the return value, which is not what you thought it was.

Use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead, although this is odd usage, you're probably heading in the wrong direction with whatever you're trying to do with this...

Comment: I tried that, but it's not loading the file even though it's in the same directory.

Comment: What does file_get_contents() return? use print_r(file_get_contents($your_path)); to see what it returns.

Comment: Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(test.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...

Comment: Your path must be incorrect. Is your path quoted correctly as a string and in the same directory as the running PHP script?

Comment: yes, it's the exact same path as I used for require_once

Comment: Try setting the second parameter to true, so file_get_contents("./test.js", true);

Comment: Nope: file_get_contents(./test.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...

Comment: Found the issue, I have to do this: `echo file_get_contents(dirname( __FILE__ )."/test.js", true);`

Comment: You don't "have" to use dirname(__FILE__). That's a bodge because you've used absolute path to the root of the drive. / is the root of the drive, it isn't relative to the current directory. "./" is, so you probably wanted file_get_contents("./test.js"), or just file_get_contents("file.js")

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import a script "on the fly" and want it to be only loaded once, we can "combine" `require_once` with a script, like so:

```
<script>
  <?php require_once('your-script.js'); ?>
</script>
<div>Foo</div>
```

Now, let's you have a component with that structure. If some of your templates includes that component many times, your script will only be embedded once, in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove echo from "echo require_once("test.js");"

you can include the js file by following method

```
<script src="test.js" language="javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: That won't work, as I need the javascript to load inline with the HTML.

Comment: In php file, closing the php tag, use the above tag.

Comment: Using require_once to include js file is really a bad habit.
One should include external js through <script></script>.

Comment: @SilverBullet why do you consider it a "bad habit"?